# How to fix a crash in SwiftUI caused by AnimatorBox.value(in:for:)？

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app. The app keeps crashing with the following error message:

I've checked the crash logs in Xcode's Organizer > App > Reports > Crashes section and found this to be the source of the problem, but I don't understand.

Crash Log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016b53fff0
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x000000016b53fff0
VM Region Info: 0x16b53fff0 is in 0x16b53c000-0x16b540000;  bytes after start: 16368  bytes before end: 15
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      mapped file              151c70000-151dc8000 [ 1376K] r--/r-- SM=ALI  ...t_id=1b2d25c5
      GAP OF 0x19774000 BYTES
--->  STACK GUARD              16b53c000-16b540000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  ... for thread 0
      Stack                    16b540000-16b63c000 [ 1008K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 0
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [57298]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001bdc447d4 _swift_getGenericMetadata(swift::MetadataRequest, void const* const*, swift::TargetTypeContextDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*) + 8 (Metadata.cpp:861)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001bdc21e08 __swift_instantiateCanonicalPrespecializedGenericMetadata + 36 (<compiler-generated>:0)
2   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c74f19b0 AnimatorBox.value(in:for:) + 168 (Animation.swift:167)
3   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c7475248 AnyAnimator.value(in:for:) + 156 (Animation.swift:116)
4   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c74768d8 DefaultCombiningAnimator.value(in:for:) + 688 (DefaultCombiningAnimation.swift:26)
5   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c74f19b0 AnimatorBox.value(in:for:) + 168 (Animation.swift:167)
6   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c7475248 AnyAnimator.value(in:for:) + 156 (Animation.swift:116)
7   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c74768d8 DefaultCombiningAnimator.value(in:for:) + 688 (DefaultCombiningAnimation.swift:26)
8   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c74f19b0 AnimatorBox.value(in:for:) + 168 (Animation.swift:167)
9   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c7475248 AnyAnimator.value(in:for:) + 156 (Animation.swift:116)
10  SwiftUI                         0x00000001c74768d8 DefaultCombiningAnimator.value(in:for:) + 688 (DefaultCombiningAnimation.swift:26)
```

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this crash and how to fix it? I'd appreciate any guidance or advice on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: add more content

Comment: Hi, we are seeing the same issue and have no other information as we cannot reproduce the crash on our side... Did you solve this?